# help on trigger logic

Tags: apex, trigger

I'm learning triggers and need some help with the logic. Election_Position__c looks up to Election__c and Contact objects. 
A contact can be assigned only one position in an election. 
In other words, a contact cannot have more than one position in an election.
Here's where I got so far:

```
trigger TestTrigger on Election_Position__c (before insert, before update) {
    Map<Id, Set<Id>> electionToWorkersMap = new Map<Id, Set<Id>>();
    for(Election_Position__c ep: [SELECT Election__c, Assigned_Worker__c FROM Election_Position__c]){
        if(!electionToWorkersMap.containsKey(ep.Election__c)){
            electionToWorkersMap.put(ep.Election__c, new Set<Id>());
        }
        electionToWorkersMap.get(ep.Election__c).add(ep.Assigned_Worker__c);
    }
    for(Election_Position__c ep : Trigger.new){
        if(electionToWorkersMap.containsKey(ep.Assigned_Worker__c)){
            ep.addError('The worker already is assigned to this election, please select another election');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wait, one position in *any* election or one per?

Comment: One per. A contact can be assigned in multiple elections but can only be assigned one position in each election. Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are comparing ids of different type. Your map key has an `Election__c` id, but you are looking for a `Contact` key. You want:

```
electionToWorkersMap.containsKey(ep.Election__c) &&
    electionToWorkersMap.get(ep.Election__c).containsKey(ep.Assigned_Worker_c);
```

---

My initial understanding was they can only be added to one `Election`, which would look like:

```
Set<Id> existingWorkerIds = new Set<Id>();
for (AggregateResult aggregate : [
    SELECT Assigned_Worker__c workerId FROM Election_Position__c
    GROUP BY Assigned_Worker__c
])
    existingWorkerIds.add((Id)aggregate.get('workerId'));
for (Election_Position__c record : trigger.new)
    if (existingWorkerIds.contains(ep.Assigned_Worker__c))
        record.addError('message');
```

Comment: But that means they can't be in more than one election...

Answer (score 3):

```
trigger TestTrigger on Election_Position__c (after insert, after update) {
    Map<Election_Position__c, Id> positions = new Map<Election_Position__c, Id>();
    Set<Id> assignedWorkers = new Set<Id>();
    for(Election_Position__c record: Trigger.new) {
        positions.put(new Election_Position__c(Election__c=record.Election__c, Assigned_Worker__c=record.Assigned_Worker__c), record.Id);
        assignedWorkers.add(record.Assigned_Worker__c);
    }

    for(Election_Position__c record: [SELECT Election__c, Assigned_Worker__c FROM Election_Position__c WHERE Assigned_Worker__c IN :assignedWorkers]){
        Election_Position__c key = new Election_Position__c(Election__c=record.Election__c, Assigned_Worker__c=record.Assigned_Worker__c);
        if(positions.containsKey(key)) {
            Trigger.newMap.get(positions.get(key)).addError('The worker already is assigned to this election, please select another election');
        }
    }
}
```

This version uses Election_Position__c records as keys into a map, making it efficient to find duplicates without managing nested collections, and using a minimal amount of memory.

Answer (score 1):

Your map key contains Id of Election but you are trying to check whether it contains Assigned_Worker__c(Contact) which will always be false.

So change your if condition to

```
if(electionToWorkersMap.get(ep.Election__c).contains(ep.Assigned_Worker__c))
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: This solution will break if there are no positions assigned to the election yet.

Comment: I got that after you did edit to your answer but kept it so that OP will have the option to look worst case aswell.

Comment: Gotcha makes sense.